# What's wrong in this SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

What's wrong in this SQL query?

> UPDATE Student SET Id = '3', Email = '3@3.com', Password = '20105',
>   Name = '3', FatherName = '3', CNIC = 3            , ContactNo = 3
>   , Section = 'G', Department = 'EE', Image =
>   '10414450_624151571051295_2997621265926572989_n.png', SemesterId = 1
>   WHERE Id = '3'

If the table of Student is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [Id]         VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
    [Email]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Password]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Name]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [FatherName] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [CNIC]       CHAR (13)     NOT NULL,
    [ContactNo]  CHAR (11)     NOT NULL,
    [Department] VARCHAR (10)  NULL,
    [Degree]     VARCHAR (10)  NULL,
    [Image]      VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SemesterId] SMALLINT      NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([Department]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_ToDegree] FOREIGN KEY ([Degree]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Degree] ([Name])
);
```

Thanks in advance dudes!

Comment: What's wrong in the error?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: `Section = 'G'` what is 'Section'? should it be 'Department'?

Comment: Your table didn't have the field section which you tried to update

Comment: Thanks. @Nikhil Agrawal That's the problem. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Section` Column in your table. I think it should be `Degree`.

So your query will be

`UPDATE Student SET Id = '3', Email = '3@3.com', Password = '20105', Name = '3', FatherName = '3', CNIC = 3, ContactNo = 3, Department = 'EE', Degree = 'G', Image = '10414450_624151571051295_2997621265926572989_n.png', SemesterId = 1 WHERE Id = '3'`

Comment: Thanks. @Nikhil Agrawal That's the problem. Sorry

Comment: I tried but I cannot accept answer before 10 minutes....

Answer (score 0):

In your query "section" column is not exist in your definition.

Check this

```
I execute this commented script to check your issue. 
--CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
--    [Id]         VARCHAR (10)  NOT NULL,
--    [Email]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
--    [Password]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
--    [Name]       VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
--    [FatherName] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
--    [CNIC]       CHAR (13)     NOT NULL,
--    [ContactNo]  CHAR (11)     NOT NULL,
--    [Department] VARCHAR (10)  NULL,
--    [Degree]     VARCHAR (10)  NULL,
--    [Image]      VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
--    [SemesterId] SMALLINT      NULL,
--    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
--    --,FOREIGN KEY ([Department]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([Id]),
--    --CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_ToDegree] FOREIGN KEY ([Degree]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Degree] ([Name])
--);

--insert into student values (33, 'test@gmail.com' , 'password', 'test' , 'fathername', 'cni', '9999999', 'dept1' , 'degree1' , 'image1', 1 )

--Section column is not exist in your table 
UPDATE Student SET Id = '1', Email = '3@3.com', Password = '20105', Name = '3', FatherName = '3', CNIC = 3 , ContactNo = 3
--, Section = 'G'   
,Department = 'EE', Image = '10414450_624151571051295_2997621265926572989_n.png', SemesterId = 1 WHERE Id = '1'

select * from student
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This Answer i have change your query

```
UPDATE Student 
SET Id = '3', Email = '3@3.com', Password = '20105', 
    Name = '3', FatherName = '3', CNIC = '3', ContactNo = '3',
    Department = 'EE', Degree = 'G', 
    Image = '10414450_624151571051295_2997621265926572989_n.png', 
    SemesterId = 1 
WHERE Id = '3'
```